# How do I delete my associated Logins?

Tags: support, login

Under the Login's page where it shows the social networks you can login with,

How does one delete those ?

Comment: In your profile page, click the "my logins" link. In the popup, click the "remove" link for those you wish to remove.

Comment: @Oded - I do not see a remove link on any of them

Comment: You need to do this on any Q&A site, not stackexchange.com.

Comment: strange... it's there now.  Doesn't show up when i tried from SO.  Is this different for each site ?